# Match/compare a value with members of an array

Tags: ruby

I have an array containing four ranges:

```
[0..25, 26..50, 51..75, 76..100]
```

How can I match/compare an integer with this array? For example:

```
28 # => 26..50
89 # => 76..100
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you looked at documentation of [`Range` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html) and could you identify any method that will help you?  There are at least two methods that fits the bill.

Comment: Good hint! I've looked at the array methods but could'nt find something useful. I'll try if this one does the job for me: 
`cover?(obj) → true or false`

Comment: Excellent!  That should do the job for you.

Comment: @BerryGJS could you provide some context? What are you doing with the array and/or the match?

Comment: If your array is always of the form `arr = [0..m, m+1..2m,...,m*(n-1)+1..m*n]`, as in your example, then `x` is covered by the range `arr[(x-1)/m]` if `x > 0` and by the range `arr[0]` if `x = 0`.

Comment: When you give an example please assign a variable to each input object (`arr = [0..25, 26..50, 51..75, 76..100]`). That way readers can refer to the variable (`arr`) in answers and comments without having to define it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - interesting! But let's say m=25 and x=98. That does not fit any range: (98-1)/25=?

Comment: Berry, `97/25 #=> 3`, so `98` is in the range `arr[3] #=> 76..100`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - OK, I understand; it uses mod. So maybe I'll try to use this one. Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @WandMaker said, there are range methods that can help you here

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check if an int is contained within your ranges?

```
my_array.each do |range|
  if range.cover?(my_integer)
    return true
  end
end
return false
```

Comment: This what I did. I matched the number with a hash [:range => :score]. So, I have 4 ranges, scoring "bad" "so so" "ok" and "super". If my variable fits a range, it returns the score:

`def disk(disk_score)
     options = { (0..25) => options.where(:number => 1).take,
                (26..50) => options.where(:number => 2).take,
                (51..75) => options.where(:number => 3).take,
               (76..100) => options.where(:number => 4).take }
    disk_options.each do | range, option |
    disk_score = option if range.cover?(disk_score) == true
    end
    disk_score 
    end`

Answer (score 5):

```
[0..25, 26..50, 51..75, 76..100].find{|r| r.include?(28)} # => 26..50
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196504/match-compare-a-value-with-members-of-an-array/35227701#comment58141114_35196731):

> I matched the number with a hash [:range => :score]. So, I have 4 ranges, scoring "bad" "so so" "ok" and "super". If my variable fits a range, it returns the score

You can use a `case` statement:

```
def score(number)
  case number
  when  0..25  then :bad
  when 26..50  then :so_so
  when 51..75  then :ok
  when 76..100 then :super
  end
end

score(28) #=> :so_so
score(89) #=> :super
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you just need to know if it matches any range:

```
p [0..25, 26..50, 51..75, 76..100].any?{|range| range.cover?(my_int) } #=> true
```

Note that `cover?` is faster than `include?`, and is safe to use when working with integers.